# Randomizing regex string replacement

Tags: c#, regex, string, random

I'm trying to do two things here, first, provide pseudo localization (leet speak) conversion for a string, and secondly, randomize the chance to replace a character contained in the string based on a percentage ratio, IE: every 5%-30% of the time...

Also, in addition to this, I'm needing to add a fixed number or special chars in either the start of the string, middle or end (randomized).

Just so everyones aware, this is for a random password generator.

My question is, how would I incorporate said functionality into the code base I currently am working with? better yet, how can I do this efficiently?

Thank you for any help you're able to provide with this.

```
namespace pseudoLocalizer
{
class RegexTuple
{
    Regex thisRegex;
    string replaceWith;

    public RegexTuple(string expression, string replacement)
    {
        thisRegex = new Regex(expression);
        replaceWith = replacement;

    }

    public string GetReplaceWith()
    {
        return replaceWith;
    }

    public Regex GetRegex()
    {
        return thisRegex;
    }
}

class pLocalizeEngine
{
    //leet table.
    RegexTuple[] arrRegexTuples = {            
    new RegexTuple ("a", @"@"),
    new RegexTuple ("A", @"4"),
    new RegexTuple ("b", @"6"),
    new RegexTuple ("B", @"8"),
    new RegexTuple ("c", @"<"),
    new RegexTuple ("C", @"("),
    new RegexTuple ("d", @"d"),
    new RegexTuple ("D", @"D"),
    new RegexTuple ("e", @"3"),
    new RegexTuple ("E", @"3"),
    new RegexTuple ("f", @"f"),
    new RegexTuple ("F", @"F"),
    new RegexTuple ("g", @"6"),
    new RegexTuple ("G", @"9"),
    new RegexTuple ("h", @"#"),
    new RegexTuple ("H", @"#"),
    new RegexTuple ("i", @"!"),
    new RegexTuple ("I", @"1"),
    new RegexTuple ("j", @"j"),
    new RegexTuple ("J", @"J"),
    new RegexTuple ("k", @"k"),
    new RegexTuple ("K", @"K"),
    new RegexTuple ("l", @"1"),
    new RegexTuple ("L", @"7"),
    new RegexTuple ("m", @"m"),
    new RegexTuple ("M", @"M"),
    new RegexTuple ("n", @"~"),
    new RegexTuple ("N", @"N"),
    new RegexTuple ("o", @"0"),
    new RegexTuple ("O", @"0"),
    new RegexTuple ("p", @"p"),
    new RegexTuple ("P", @"P"),
    new RegexTuple ("q", @"q"),
    new RegexTuple ("Q", @"Q"),
    new RegexTuple ("r", @"2"),
    new RegexTuple ("R", @"2"),
    new RegexTuple ("s", @"$"),
    new RegexTuple ("S", @"5"),
    new RegexTuple ("t", @"+"),
    new RegexTuple ("T", @"7"),
    new RegexTuple ("u", @"u"),
    new RegexTuple ("U", @"U"),
    new RegexTuple ("v", @"v"),
    new RegexTuple ("V", @"V"),
    new RegexTuple ("w", @"w"),
    new RegexTuple ("W", @"W"),
    new RegexTuple ("x", @"x"),
    new RegexTuple ("X", @"X"),
    new RegexTuple ("y", @"y"),
    new RegexTuple ("Y", @"Y"),
    new RegexTuple ("z", @"2"),
    new RegexTuple ("Z", @"2"),
};

    public pLocalizeEngine()
    {
        //
    }

    public string Localize(string oldString)
    {
        string pLocalString = oldString;
        foreach (RegexTuple tuple in arrRegexTuples)
        {
            pLocalString = tuple.GetRegex().Replace(pLocalString, tuple.GetReplaceWith());
        }
        return pLocalString;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tend to agree, you say I am trying to do `X`... here is my code `Y`... then nothing else, no problem, no question... does it not compile? does it simply not produce what you want? What?

Comment: My apology, the original question has been edited.

Comment: OK - a little better - there's actually a question mark now, but it's essentially just 'please look at my code `Y` and tell me what to do to achieve `X`' - there's no indication of where the problem might be or what part of your desired algorithm is your primary issue? Do you need to know how to simulate randomness? How to execute a regex? How to get a seed word? All you have provided is "Here is my goal. How do I do it?" -- If you want someone to do it all for you, I think code golf _might_ be helpful - just don't tell them I sent you.

Comment: Basically, this is very similar to most of [your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/995820/user995820), where you post ten times more code than question. The difference lies in the fact that your other questions mostly focused on a single aspect of your issue. This question would require addressing multiple facets of the problem, but only after running all of your code to even understand what parts are not addressed. This is a free community, people are giving of their time, but there is a limit to such generosity - do a little more work and come to us with a single issue to resolve...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you need a password generator, here is my suggestion for you:

```
private const string ValidCharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890@<()!?~+";
private Random random = new Random();

private string RandomPasswordGenerator(int length)
{
    string password = string.Empty;
    while (length > 0)
    {
        password += ValidCharacters[random.Next(0, ValidCharacters.Length - 1)];
        length--;
    }
    return password;
}
```

Comment: I do think the point is to generate a memorable password for the user, rather than a completely random set of characters, but there really is no question, so, sure +1!

Comment: Code Jockey, you are correct, that is the goal in this, I updated the original question with a question.

Comment: @CodeJockey and user995820: A "memorable" password is a "guessable" one too! A password is memorable to a user when it contains words he knows. But then a simple dictionary attack can hack that one.